# Domain Driven Development and sql indexes

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, domain-driven-design

I have some problem with persistance of DDD models in WebApi application.

Out 'stack':

- Web .net core app
- DDD
- sql (Dapper not ef core)

We have simple DDD entity model for simplicity let's just assume thats all

```cs
public class Car {
    public VIM Vim;
    // some value objects
}
```

as far as I know VIM is unique so It's gonna work as Identity for DDD model.

I want to store it in a simple sql table where will be column VIM as varchar.
And it's gonna work great because of VIM uniqness i can use it as primary key and whenever i want to stor or retrieve (then create) my DDD model I can do that by VIM.

On the other side searching for by varchar value is not efficient so a simple ID (index) comes handy for our CRUD web app.

If we want to our DDD model stay pure it supposed to be indepent from any persistance info.

While we want to create record for our Car, it's gonna work because ID gonna be generated without model knowledge same goes for Delete because we get our ID form api request.

Only problem for me is for Update action.
The flow look liek this:
retrieve Db record by ID (from request) -> create DDD model from our persistance layer -> perform update action on our DDD model

How to perform last step - save changes? Because while we cosntruct our DDD model we lost our Id (we want model to be pure). Should I perform action but there should be VIM in udpate query? Or should I keep sql ID in persistance/application layer scope?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mssql and dapper on backend

Comment: The question isn't about "SQL indexes".  Consider editing the title. Put "dapper" and "orm" tag on the question.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed two issues in your question.

- If your application is a CRUD-based application maybe you should avoid using DDD. It's going to be overkill.
- the second one refers to this sentence: *"Create a DDD model from our persistence layer"*. Mapping objects from persisted data doesn't need to go through business rules and validations. It means it doesn't need to call the same constructor that you use for creating domain objects. Because the validation once happened before persisting the data. I think this issue came from using Dapper as an ORM. ORMs like EF and NHibernate don't need public constructors to create mapped objects.

Comment: It's just a concept. I didn;t want to overcomplicate things.

Comment: It's just a concept. I didn;t want to overcomplicate things. There is no issue from Dapper. 
If i want to update my DDD model (change sth like color etc.) i have to create my model from persistance layer. I can easly do that i got Car ID from api request. I can change proeprty as well. But the last step is to store that in table again. But how can i do that when in DDD models we do not have ID property because ID belongs to Persistance layer. Should i write my udpate query by VIM (from performance point of view is not efficient)

Comment: ID is a concept in the domain. How do you identify an instance? That's why ID is a domain model concept. Mapping it into persistent terminology is a persistent concern and should be avoided (persistence ignorance).

Comment: Yes, i totally agree. I asked the question how can i store my Car entity and do not lose db performance? I can easly looking by Car's VIM but its not efficient from sql point of view. So ID comes handy but I cannot add it to ID Domain model so what choice do I have?

Comment: Does your business use cases use this handy ID or the domain ID? If they are driven by the handy ID, then consider changing your domain ID to that handy ID. Otherwise, the performance would not be achieved because the use cases use the domain ID to fetch the instance not the handy ID.